# Самолёт выровнялся/выравнялся

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Самолёт выровнялся/выравнялся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: **самолет **выровнялся**.**

**Ровный полет** — это полет без изменения высоты.

*"И вот самолёт **выровнялся** и как будто замер на одном месте, и ничего больше не происходило, кроме ровного гула двигателей".*
[Мой первый полет](https://kamerata.org/moy-pervyy-polet/)

[https://kartaslov.ru/как-правильно-пишется-словосочетание/самолёт+выровнялся](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F)

**ВЫРОВНЯТЬСЯ**,  св. 1. только 3 л. Стать ровным, плоским, гладким. Лёд на катке выровнялся. 2. только 3 л. Расположиться, направиться по прямой линии в вертикальной или **горизонтальной** плоскости. Выйдя из пике, **самолёты выровнялись** в нескольких метрах от земли. // Стать прямым; расположиться по прямой. Фронт выровнялся. Шеренга выровнялась.